# system collection generic list<string> string[] cannot be converted

Tags: c#

In Datagridvied, I want to delete the candidates in rows with selected checkboxes from the database in bulk. However, I am getting an error that List cannot be converted to string[].

- aday class

  namespace ESMWebServis
  {
  public class Aday

  ```
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string adi { get; set; }
        public string soyadi { get; set; }
        public List<string> secilmisler { get; set; }
    }
  ```

  }
- code in db operations class

  ```
  public outputType secilenid(Aday a)  
    {
        List<string> secilenler = new List<string>();
        secilenler.AddRange(a.secilmisler);
        foreach (string s in secilenler)
        {
            cmd = new MySqlCommand("Delete From tbl_adaykayit where id='" + s + "' ", baglan);
            baglantikontrol();
           returnValueOutputType= cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()>0? outputType.islembasarili:outputType.islembasarisiz;
            baglantikontrol();
        }
        baglantikontrol();
        return returnValueOutputType;


    }
  ```
- code on webservice side

  [WebMethod]

  ```
    public outputType secilenID(Aday a)
    {
        using (DB_islemleri db = new DB_islemleri())
        {
            return db.secilenid(a);

        }
    }
  ```
- UI code

  List secilen = new List();

  ```
            for (int i = 0; i < dgv_adaylar.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                row = dgv_adaylar.Rows[i];
                if (Convert.ToBoolean(row.Cells["secim"].Value) == true)
                {
                    string secilenid = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                    secilen.Add(secilenid);

                }
            }
            ESMWebServis.WebService1 ws = new ESMWebServis.WebService1();
            ESMWebServis.outputType returnType = ws.yeniadaykayit(new ESMWebServis.Aday() {secilmisler= secilen });
  ```

Comment: please use ***parameterised queries*** - building SQL queries by concatenation etc. is a recipe for disaster. not only is it a source for many hard to debug syntax errors, it's also a wide, open gate for ***[SQL Injection attacks](https://bobby-tables.com/)***.

Comment: What is the relationship with C?

Comment: Looping and executing query can be *very slow*. Try combining all the items to delete in *one* query: `"Delete From tbl_adaykayit where id in ({string.Join(", ", s)})";`

Comment: Why do you do secilenler.AddRange(a.secilmisler); instead of using secilmisler property of a? And the foreach would be: foreach (string s in a.secilenler), you don't need to declare a new list of string. Also, in which point of the code is the exception raised?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt if you want a local `List<T>` - `secilenler` - at all: why don't we pass existing `a.secilmisler`?
Please, note, that executing *query* in a *loop* can be *very slow*: let's try combining all ids to delete
into a *single query* with `in` instead of `=`:

```
//TODO: please, checkk capitalize names: secilenid -> SecilenId etc.
public outputType secilenid(Aday a) {
  // Or throw ParameterNullException
  if (a?.secilmisler == null)
    return outputType.islembasarisiz;
    
  // Single query with all ids to delete 
  string sql = 
    $@"delete
         from tbl_adaykayit
        where id in ({string.Join(", ", a.secilmisler)})";

  // wrap IDisposable into using
  using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, baglan)) {
    baglantikontrol();

    return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0
      ? outputType.islembasarili
      : outputType.islembasarisiz; 
  }
}
```